# Can my PID controller have negative p value and positive i value for a PID logic

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

I am building my first PID controller.

My process variable and my actuator value are inversly related, meaning if actuator value increases process variable decreases, and vice versa.

So I have tried with a negative value of P and positive value of I.

It works fine for a while and then process variable keeps increasing with actuator  becoming as 0.

Can some one help me with what might be the reason for this? Is it okay to have P as negative and I as postive?

Comment: Could you keep the gains positive, but simply invert the output of your controller at the end?

Comment: Likely if P has to be negative then I does also.  But there may be more going on than just that.  Suggest adding  a lot more info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Except when you're driving a very strange plant, you want the sign of all of your gains to be the same -- all positive, or all negative.

If you have a fairly normal plant (i.e. it has a minimum phase response in dynamic systems terms, meaning that all of its poles and zeros are in the left-half plane) then you need to use negative gains for *both* proportional and integral gains, or you need to take @gregb212's suggestion and do your calculation, then multiply it by -1 at the end.

Comment: In literature and google - positive and negative are called direct vs reverse acting pid.  You could google that.